# Converting from decimal to hexadecimal for MultiversX blockchain

Tags: bash, hex, multiversx

I am trying to do some smart contract testing for MultiversX blockchain with multiple wallets and different token amounts.

The MultiversX blockchain requires some hexadecimal encodings for the Smart Contract interaction. The problem is that my hex encoding matches some conversions like in this webpage http://207.244.241.38/elrond-converters/ but some others are not:

For example here is my for loop:

```
for line in $file; do
    MAIAR_AMOUNT=$(echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $2}')

    MAIAR_AMOUNT_HEX=$(printf "%04x" $MAIAR_AMOUNT)

    echo -e "$MAIAR_AMOUNT > $MAIAR_AMOUNT_HEX"
done
```

And here is the output

```
620000000000 > 905ae13800
1009000000000 > eaed162a00
2925000000000 > 2a907960200
31000000000 > 737be7600
111000000000 > 19d81d9600
```

The first one is the decimal value I want to convert, the second is the hexadecimal.
Now if I compare the results with http://207.244.241.38/elrond-converters/

A value like **2925000000000** is **02a907960200** not **2a907960200** like I have in my output. (notice the 0 at the beginning)

But a value like **620000000000** is matching with the website **905ae13800**

Of course adding a **0** in front of **%04x** is not gonna help me.

Now if I go to this guy repository (link below) I can see there is a calculus made, but I don't know JavaScript/TypeScript so I don't know how to interpret it in Bash.

https://github.com/bogdan-rosianu/elrond-converters/blob/main/src/index.ts#L30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks the converted hex string should have even number of digits.
Then would you please try:

```
MAIAR_AMOUNT_HEX=$(printf "%x" "$MAIAR_AMOUNT")
(( ${#MAIAR_AMOUNT_HEX} % 2 )) && MAIAR_AMOUNT_HEX="0$MAIAR_AMOUNT_HEX"
```

The condition `(( ${#MAIAR_AMOUNT_HEX} % 2 ))` is evaluated to be true if
`$MAIAR_AMOUNT_HEX` has odd length. Then `0` is prepended to adjust
the length.

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm, I tried something similar to this, but instead of %x I had %x04 and the outputs were better, but not perfect like in your example

Answer (score 0):

The `4` in `%04x` is how many digits to pad the output to. Use `%012x` to pad the output to 12 hex digits.

```
❯ printf '%012x' 2925000000000
02a907960200
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by doing it this way it is miss formatting my other values by adding double 0 in front of them and the blockchain will interpret only the ones similar to 2925000000000. At this point there should be some formatting based on the decimal length?